# Setting a default value for a bool

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, boolean, critical-section

I am working on a Queue class using threads in C++ (Windows 10 Visual Studio).

In my constructor, I start by setting a boolean error value to false. Immediately after, I attempt to initialise the critical section. If the there is a problem, the bool is set to true, otherwise it stays as false. I check this value in the main function (not shown) and end the program if the crit sec is not initialised (bool is false).

Constructor code:

```
Queue() {
        // ERROR_CRIT is bool: false = no error in initialising crit section, true = there is an error
        ERROR_CRIT = false;
        // check init 
        if (!InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount(&CritSec, 0x00000400)) {
            ERROR_INIT_CRIT_SEC = true;
        }
        totalCustomers = 0;
        currentReadIndex = 0;
        currentWriteIndex = 0;
        customerNum = 0;
    };
```

My question is: what types of booleans should I have default set to true or false ? I have thought about this many times while writing other programs and I am not sure when to set a default value for a bool unless it is obvious. Sometimes it seems fair to start with either value. I feel it would be strange to set an error bool to start as true, but starting it as false also may be strange.

In the real world or in a company, would I remove the line 3 and add an else statement to the if with `else {ERROR_CRIT = false;}` ? Would this improve readability ? This is probably preference but what is often seen in the real world programming ?

Thank you in advance :D

Comment: `ERROR_INIT_CRIT_SEC = !InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount(&CritSec, 0x00000400);`?

Comment: I would set a default value for a bool if the intended meaning of the variable is such that, at the time it's initialized, you can tell which value it ought to have. Same with any variable, really, not just a bool. In this case the answer to "has there been an error initializing the critical section?" at the time `ERROR_CRIT` is initialized is "no", so `ERROR_CRIT` defaulting to `false` seems reasonable to me.

Comment: Replace all the `bool`s and their setting and testing with throwing an exception.  Why - the `Queue` object is not in a good state and this should be exceptional error.

Comment: General rule of thumb: If you cannot successfully construct, throw an exception and bail. A constructor returns a valid object (baring two phase construction) and if it cannot, it should force the program to handle the problem or die..

Comment: Thank you all. Could you elaborate on the exception throwing ? Would I be making a separate member function which checks for the error value ? Could I make it private and have the constructor use it or would I call it in the main function making it public member ? I have not used exception throws in some time

Comment: When the exception is thrown you do not get an object. You can't call any test methods  because you don't have an object. You either have a separate path of code that makes do without the object, you repeat until you successfully construct the object, or you scream for help (report the error) and abort the program. Often you'll use a combination of 2 and 3: make a few retries and then report and die.

Comment: @HusamChekfa like this  `if (!::InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount(...)) throw my_system_error( ::GetLastError() );`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A much better approach is to prevent the queue from existing *at all* if the critical section cannot be created. This establishes a tighter class invariant for the `Queue` class, which simplifies its implementation.

This is done by throwing an exception:

```
Queue() {
    // check init 
    if (!InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount(&CritSec, 0x00000400)) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create the critical section");
    }
    totalCustomers = 0;
    currentReadIndex = 0;
    currentWriteIndex = 0;
    customerNum = 0;
};
```

This way, you don't ever need to check for `ERROR_CRIT`, since the Queue existing is enough information to guarantee that the critical section is correctly initialized.

Comment: Ah so the exception would be built into the constructor rather than by a separate member function ? The catch here would be in the main and I could decide what happens to the program then ? By throwing, the rest of the constructor would be ignored correct ? Only the if statement would be completed if the throw occurs ?

Comment: @HusamChekfa Exactly, Throwing an exception inside of a constructor will abort the object creation process, as well as any code that follows the creation of the object until a matching `try` block is exited. How to deal with this in the `main()` depends on what you want to do when the failure happens. If you were going to exit the program, then you can just let the exception be unhandled, and that'll do the equivalent. Otherwise, you need to catch/handle the exception in accordance to the desired behavior.

Comment: Thank you. Getting to avoid making the bool altogether and using the throw method in its stead is perfect

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with the accepted answer in general (and upvoted it), I want to add that established approach in modern OS is that in-process synchronization primitives do not fail for the reasons of lack of resources or something.

They can only fail if used improperly, if there's a diagnostic for such failures.

This confirms with `InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-initializecriticalsectionandspincount#return-value):

> ### Return value
>
> This function always succeeds and returns a nonzero value.
>
> **Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:**  *blah blah blah*

The reason is that when synchronization primitives fail it is very complex to recover, but it is possible to have synchronization primitives that never fail. So on a modern OS failure handling code can never execute, and in order OS it still not likely to make the program recover.

C++ `std::mutex` ad other C++ mutexes align with this, and never throws due to lack of memory or resources (specifically `std::mutex` is even `constexpr` constructible, although Visual C++ violates it). New C++20 primitives also do not throw exceptions.

So you can just write:

```
Queue() noexcept {
    InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount(&CritSec, 0x00000400);
    totalCustomers = 0;
    currentReadIndex = 0;
    currentWriteIndex = 0;
    customerNum = 0;
};
```

or, if your're paranoid:

```
Queue() noexcept {
    // check init 
    if (!InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount(&CritSec, 0x00000400)) {
        __fastfail(1); // something terrible happened, cannot recover
    }
    totalCustomers = 0;
    currentReadIndex = 0;
    currentWriteIndex = 0;
    customerNum = 0;
};
```